# "AttributeError" using grid() function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I got an error using gride: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'".

This is my code:

```
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg="black")

    # Creates labels
    tk.Label(root, image=logo1).pack()

    # Creates buttons
    tk.Button(root, image=logo2, command=root.destroy).pack().grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Button(root, image=logo3, command=root.destroy).pack().grid(row=0, column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You must not use `pack()` and `grid()` simultaneously. So remove `.pack()` for your widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two packing managers in the same time and you're using them wrong.

A pack call will return None, and you're trying to assign grid call to that None.

Do like this:

```
tk.Button(root, image=logo2, command=root.destroy).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(root, image=logo3, command=root.destroy).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Or with pack manager instead of grid:

```
tk.Button(root, image=logo2, command=root.destroy).pack()
tk.Button(root, image=logo3, command=root.destroy).pack()
```